# How to make Redis data user specific?

Tags: python, flask, session, redis

The below simplified code is part of a multi-user platform in Flask.

```
r = redis.Redis(host='localhost', port=6379, db=0, password=None, socket_timeout=None)

def button_func():
    # some executions
    r.set(my_data, encodedNumpyData)
    return jsonify('success')

def another_func():
    r.get(my_data)
    # some execcutions
    return render_template('some.html')
```

How do I ensure this data stored and retrieved from redis db is user-specific and does not get shared between different users?

Note: I am using sessions to handle users

Comment: Make the key user specific.

Comment: There are n number of users...how do we make the key user specific?

Comment: Asked like this: incorporate `n` in the key.

Comment: prepend the username/user-id to `my_data`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there are multiple things that you can do:

1. You can use different in memory db provided by redis. Redis supports
   upto 16 DBs. You can store keys for different users in different db.
   To fetch them connect with respective DB. Data in different DB cannot be accessed i.e. if you make connection
   to DB 0, you cannot fetch data from DB 1.
2. Implement Redis ACL - If you are using Redis version 6+, you can
   leverage the feature of using ACL(Access Control Lists). You can
   create users with passwords for each user and pass these credentials
   while making Redis connection. You can even add permissions/commands
   etc. to the users. So, Prefix the keys with user id like userid:data and create users with permission to access keys with their respective prefixes. So, any user will not be able access other user's data.